# Mobile website for different resolution devices

Tags: mobile, view, resolution

I am creating a mobile website. I want to load specific views for phones with lower resolution and other views for phones with higher resolution say example,

I want menu page to be in the form of list rows for lower resolution devices and
in the form of icons for higher resolution.

What approach should i use?

--Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Boostrap responsive design is looks suitable for the scenario.

Have a look at this library from twitter . http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Can u explain how content transformation happens in bootstrap?